# C: find the angle between two 3D-vectors

Tags: c, vector

I wrote a code which should calculate the angle between two given 3D vectors following this formula:

$\theta = \cos^{-1} [\frac{v.v'}{|v||v'|}] = \cos^{-1} [\frac{aa' + bb'+cc'}{\sqrt{a^2 + b^2 + c^2} \sqrt{a'^2 + b'^2 + c'^2}}]$

This is the code:

```
#include <math.h>

float v1[3] = {0, 1, 2};
float v2[3] = {2, 2, 2};
float angle;

float dotProd(float *vec1, float *vec2) {
    return vec1[0]*vec2[0] + vec1[1]*vec2[1] + vec1[2]*vec2[2];
}

float norm(float *vec){
    float res;
    for (int i=0; i<3; i++)
        res += pow(vec[i], 2);
    return sqrt(res);
}

float angleBetween(float *vec1, float *vec2){
    return acosf(dotProd(vec1, vec2) / (norm(vec1) * norm(vec2)));
}

int main(){
    angle = angleBetween(v1, v2) * 180 / M_PI;
    printf("%f", angle);
}
```

The problem is that it returns a wrong angle. (I checked with geogebra and the right one with *v1 = {0, 1, 2}, v2 = {2, 2, 2}* is 39.2)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to initialise your variables, or they will contain whatever value the memory that was allocated for them contains. In this case, changing  the first line of `float norm(float *vec)` to `float res = 0.0;` will fix your code.

Answer (score 3):

If you compile with `-Wall`, you'll get a hint:

```
$ gcc -Wall angle.c
angle.c:14:9: warning: variable 'res' is uninitialized when used here [-Wuninitialized]
        res += pow(vec[i], 2);
        ^~~
angle.c:12:14: note: initialize the variable 'res' to silence this warning
    float res;
```

You want to initialize `res` to zero, presumably.

There's another warning, but it is unrelated to this error. Still, you'll also want to `#include` the `stdio.h` header if you are using `printf()`.

Get into the habit of compiling with warnings turned on. It can save you a lot of time with debugging.